# How can one really create a process using Unix.create_process in OCaml?

Tags: unix, ocaml

I have tried

```
let _ = Unix.create_process "ls" [||] Unix.stdin Unix.stdout Unix.stderr
```

in utop, it will crash the whole thing.

If I write that into a `.ml` and compile and run, it will crash the terminal and my ubuntu will throw a system error.

But why?

Comment: I haven't used the unix module much. It seems `"ls"` needs to be in the array. The documentation doesn't make that statement though. I don't have any crashing when I execute this statement as is -- an, "A NULL argv[0] was passed through an exec system call.", but that's it. `let inchan,outchan = Unix.open_process "ls";;` is probably what you want in this case, of course if you're simplifying the situation then hopefully someone else can help.

Comment: @nlucaroni If i have a executable like "test.native", and I do `let _ = Unix.create_process "./test.native" [||] Unix.stdin Unix.stdout Unix.stderr`, it worked

Comment: `Unix.create_process "ls" [|""|] Unix.stdin Unix.stdout Unix.stderr;;` will work. Could this be how `[||]` is represented when making syscalls?

Comment: @nlucaroni yes, that worked. but why `[||]` worked for a simple `test.native` inside which `let _ = print_endline "hello"`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The right way to call it is:

```
let pid = Unix.create_process "ls" [|"ls"|] Unix.stdin Unix.stdout Unix.stderr
```

The first element of the array must be the "command" name.

On some systems `/bin/ls` is a link to some bigger executable that will look at `argv.(0)` to know how to behave (c.f. [Busybox](http://www.busybox.net/about.html)); so you really need to provide that info.

(You see more often that with `/usr/bin/vi` which is now on many systems a sym-link to `vim`).

Comment: but why [||] worked for a simple test.native inside which let _ = print_endline "hello"?

Comment: @JacksonTale: If test.native does not look at argv.(0), it will not fail.

Answer (score 5):

`Unix.create_process` actually calls `fork` and the does an `execvpe`, which itself calls the `execv` primitive (in the OCaml C implementation of the `Unix` module). 
That function then calls `cstringvect` (a helper function in the C side of the module implementation), which translates the arg parameters into an array of C string, with last entry set to `NULL`. However, `execve` and the like expect by convention (see the [`execve(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) linux man page) the first entry of that array to be the name of the program:

> *argv is an array of argument strings passed to the new program.  By
>          convention, **the first of these strings should contain the filename
>          associated with the file being executed**.*

That first entry (or rather, the copy it receives) can actually be changed by the program receiving these args, and is displayed by `ls`, `top`, etc.